# Converting Degree Minute Second Coordinates to Degrees of latitude / longitude?

Tags: degrees-minutes-seconds

I have a set of Degree Minute Second (DMS) formatted latitude/longitude; my question is how can I convert these DMS value to decimal degrees?

Comment: Do you know where these coordinates are meant to plot? Do you mean convert to Decimal Degrees? The process is very easy, and there are numerous examples both on this site and google. I would search the site, and possibly check out the Tour here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour fore tips on how to post questions on this site.

Comment: if you are looking to do this in Matlab, please add Matlab to the tags and update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the coordinates into Excel.
Split the coordinates into Degrees, Minutes and Seconds in separate cells.

Take the degrees and add the (minutes/60) and add the (seconds/3600)

```
DD+(MM/60)+(SS/3600)
```

If the coordinate is in the south or west, multiply the final answer by -1 to make it a negative value.

You can convert multiple coordinates in Excel this way, so it is not a manual process.

You do need to know, from your example, and split out the DD, MM and SS from the values you have been given.
You can save the Excel to CSV or another format which is readable in MATLAB.

Comment: @Efes06 unfortunately I am not versed in MATLAB. My answer was based on the information provided in the question. I suggest you edit the question to reflect exactly what you need, what you have tried and where you have had issues. SE is a Q&A site, not a forum. Have a look at the Tour link above for insight in how to get the most out of your question.